# Does Magnetron Sputtering need constant gas flow?

Tags: vacuum, thin-films

Does magnetron sputtering need constant Argon gas flow into the chamber or can the gas in the chamber be reused to sputter? if it  does need constant gas flow why does it need it? Thank you in advance. and sorry if this is the wrong forum